# How to setup django on apache

Tags: python, django, apache, python-3.6

I've been trying to run django on apache but I keep on getting `504 Gateway Timeout`. Here is the site conf. I've placed it in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ directory.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
 ServerName orounds.localhost 
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/orounds_pro
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/orounds_pro/orounds_pro/wsgi.py 

 WSGIDaemonProcess orounds processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/var/www/html/orounds_pro/venv/bin/python3 
 WSGIProcessGroup orounds 

 <directory /var/www/html/orounds_pro> 
   AllowOverride all 
   Require all granted 
   Options FollowSymlinks 
 </directory> 

 Alias /static/ /var/www/html/orounds_pro/static/ 

 <Directory /var/www/html/orounds_pro/static> 
  Require all granted 
 </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using python3.6 and apache 2.4.29. I installed `mod_wsgi` for apache with `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or is there anything else I should do?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
. . .

Alias /static /home/user/myproject/static
<Directory /home/user/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/user/myproject python-home=/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

Try above configuration also provide full permission to that same directory.

Comment: It's returning the same response

Comment: Have u given chmod 777 to your project

Comment: sorry for delay but yes I did that too @Jishnunand P k